# Send base64 encoded email using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email

I am trying to send base64 encoded email using CodeIgniter.
Below the code:

```
$message = base64_encode($body);
$config = Array('protocol' => 'smtp', 'smtp_host' => $smtp, 'smtp_port' => $port, 'smtp_user' => $user, 'smtp_pass' => $pass, 'mailtype' => 'html', 'charset' => 'utf-8','_bit_depths' => array('7bit', '8bit', 'base64'),'_encoding' => 'base64',);

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from($disemail, $disname);
$this->email->reply_to($disemail, $disname);
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
```

But email is not sending properly. Instead of base64 decode i have just found base64 encoded text in mail.

Here is the debug of the sending:

> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5596ca8577c5c"
>   This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
>   may not support this format.
>
> --B_ALT_5596ca8577c5c Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>
> PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PGgxPnRoaXMgaXMgaHRtbDwvaDE+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=
>
> --B_ALT_5596ca8577c5c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PGgxPnRoaXMgaXMgaHRtbDwvaDE+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=3D
>
> --B_ALT_5596ca8577c5c--

I couldn't find the exact problem. 
I am using CodeIgniter version `2.1.3` .

Comment: So what're you expecting at the recipient's side?

Comment: recipient browser will decode this.  Did not you see any encoded email ?

Comment: Set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding:` header. (A wholly base64ed body is likely to trigger more spamfilters, btw.)

Comment: @mario , `'_encoding' => 'base64'` is doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an email in base64 encode in CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7804198)

Comment: @mario , i have used their solution, but not working.

Comment: Well you probably shouldn't encode it manually then. If there is a flag for that, good chance that CI EMail would already do that on its own. Otherwise show a sample raw mail with the double- or nondecoded base64 payload.

Comment: I have tried it, but it just sent non encoded text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter version `2.1.3` has not any option for `base64` encoded email. After edit in core file, found the solution. I have shared the solution.

## Answer:

**Note: This is a hack into core file. If you just need only base64 encoded message try it. Otherwise create additional library file.**

We need to edit something in library file email.php. Which is located in "libraries/Email.php".

#### For text only message.

**1/**

First add `base64` as encode option.

Edit: `$_bit_depths` variable.

```
var $_bit_depths    = array('7bit', '8bit','base64');
```

**2/**

Then in sending controller. Add `'_encoding' => 'base64'` in email config. Check my code in question.

#### For HTML message

Follow step 1 and 2. And then step below:

**3/**

in Email.php file, find the function `function _build_message()` .

In this function, find `switch ($this->_get_content_type())` and go to `case 'html '` And delete or comment two places.
Below edited code:

```
case 'html' :

                if ($this->send_multipart === FALSE)
                {
                    $hdr .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
                    $hdr .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable";
                }
                else
                {
                    $hdr .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"" . $this->_alt_boundary . "\"" . $this->newline . $this->newline;

                    $body .= $this->_get_mime_message() . $this->newline . $this->newline;
                    $body .= "--" . $this->_alt_boundary . $this->newline;

                    // change this to text/plain to text/html
                    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
                    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " . $this->_get_encoding() . $this->newline . $this->newline;

                    // I have commented 3 lines
                    /*
                    $body .= $this->_get_alt_message() . $this->newline . $this->newline . "--" . $this->_alt_boundary . $this->newline;
                    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
                    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . $this->newline . $this->newline;
                    */
                }

                //Instead of this commented line, use line below.
                //$this->_finalbody = $body . $this->_prep_quoted_printable($this->_body) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
                $this->_finalbody = $body . $this->_body . $this->newline . $this->newline;
```

And that's it. Now base64 encoded email will send properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the header of your content as `Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64`. This is not set by default by CodeIgniter. In order to do this, you either have to modify their email library or simply extend their email class and add this header, in order to comply with standards and to ensure you do not hack the core.

Comment: Please check the answer here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804198/how-to-send-an-email-in-base64-encode-in-codeigniter

I think ` '_encoding' => 'base64' ` is doing this

Comment: @slash-bang: that depends on how you do the implementation - however the point is that the content-type header needs to change accordingly so that it can be base64 aware. I do not think it is '_encoding'. The output class header usually accepts exact HTTP header keys

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check the debug message.